# Javascript code won't work. It won't update variables on reload

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, variables

```
<div id="timelapse_speed_control">
    <?php
    $speed_var;
    $timeout_var;
    if ($this->uri->segment(4) == 1)
    {
        $speed_var = 200;
        $timeout_var = 200;
    }
    else if ($this->uri->segment(4) == 2)
    {
        $speed_var = 200;
        $timeout_var = 150;
    }
    else
    {
        $speed_var = 200;
        $timeout_var = 75;
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
        function(){
            speed_var = <?php json_encode($speed_var); ?>;
            timeout_var = <?php json_encode($timeout_var); ?>;



            $('ul.<?php echo $uri_segment; ?>').innerfade({
                speed: speed_var,
                timeout: timeout_var,
                type: 'sequence',
                containerheight: '500px'
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

The above code is basically asking what the 4th segment in the uri is and then checks it, and changes the speed and timeout of the 'timelapse' accordingly. But it isn't working. It breaks down when testing.

Any idea as to the bug in this? Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Browser output:

```
        $(document).ready(
        function(){
            speed_var = ;
            timeout_var = ;



            $('ul.jeromiedevera').innerfade({
                speed: speed_var,
                timeout: timeout_var,
                type: 'sequence',
                containerheight: '500px'
            });
        });
```

Comment: You should try saving the PHP variable to a javascript variable and check if the value is being received.

Comment: Is this file a ".php" file? If not the case you must get the value of your variables like @ICanHasCheezburger say, or rename file to ".php" to be interpret by php server

Comment: Okay, just did. Check the updated code. And it still breaks, but it's a better way to approach it. [Yes, this is using the CodeIgniter framework]

Comment: Can you tell us what's wrong? PHP error? Javascript error? Can you send us more information or source code from your brother (after php interprets php code…).

Comment: Oh, just checked if the javascript above is receiving the values. It isn't.

`speed_var = ; timeout_var = ;`

Comment: You forget `echo` before your `json_encode`

Comment: Yes, if I set `speed_var` and `timeout_var` to 200 and 75 respectively, it works, but won't work if i pass in a PHP variable.

Aha! It now works, I forgot the `echo`

Comment: Is your `json_encode` really usefull? maybe not. Just `echo` your variable ;)

Comment: Haha, no, but it's a good habit to form right? :P And thanks again for your help! So I'd have to do the variable assignments in PHP and then pass it to javascript? If so, why wouldn't doing it inside the js work?

Comment: For me the best way is to create your JS var with PHP (maybe export all variables with JSON and get it in your JS with AJAX method). Because PHP need PHP server to be interpreted. If you make JS and inside you use PHP many times you forget to save your file in ".php" and you loose time…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it add `echo` before `json_encode`:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
        function(){
            speed_var = <?php echo json_encode($speed_var); ?>;
            timeout_var = <?php echo json_encode($timeout_var); ?>;

            $('ul.<?php echo $uri_segment; ?>').innerfade({
                speed: speed_var,
                timeout: timeout_var,
                type: 'sequence',
                containerheight: '500px'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: To those who are wondering, I also had to change how I wrote the code. I initially did the checking and assigning inside the JS code, and I changed it to the way it is now; Doing the PHP first, and then passing a PHP variables to the JS code.

Comment: 1st step: your PHP create the variables and display it in JSON.
2nd step: your JS file call (with AJAX) the PHP file and get JSON.
3rd step: use JSON values in your code